# Way to test which "sibling class" an object is in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Say I have a base class "Pet" and child classes "Dog" and "Cat".  Is there a generic way I can take an arbitrary object I know is a "Pet" and test to see if it is "Dog" or "Cat"?

Comment: You can use `your_object.constructor.name` it will return Dog or Cat, not the parent class name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either ask the object for its `constructor.name` property, or if you have a reference to the class, you can use the `instanceof` operator:

```js
class Pet {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}

class Cat extends Pet {
  sayHello() { console.log(`${this.name} miaows`) }
}

class Dog extends Pet {
  sayHello() { console.log(`${this.name} barks`) }
}

const goofy = new Dog('Pluto');
const garfield = new Cat('Garfield');

console.log(goofy.constructor.name);
console.log(garfield.constructor.name);
console.log(goofy instanceof Dog);
console.log(garfield instanceof Cat);
```

Please note that `Pet` shouldn't know about the existence of `Dog` or `Cat` (and also neither of the latter two should know anything about the existence of the other).